# Choosing random Index from Array of Objects - Java

Tags: java, object, oop

I am trying to code a text based Adventure Game, but the random enemy selection does not work. Always the "Assassin" gets chosen, but I can't figure out why.

```
package defaultdfs;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {

    // System Objects
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Random rand = new Random();
    
    //OBJ
    static Entity s = new Entity("Skeleton", 200, 5, 2, 200);
    static Entity z = new Entity("Zombie", 150, 2, 1, 150);
    static Entity w = new Entity("Warrior", 175, 3, 1, 175);
    static Entity a = new Entity("Assasin", 75, 1, 1, 75);
    
    // Game Variables
    static Entity[] enemies = {w, z, s, a};
    static int maxEnemyHealth = 75;
    static int enemyAttackDam = 25;

    // Player Variables
    static int health = 100;
    static int attackDamage = 50;
    static int numHealthPot = 3;
    static int healthPotHealAmount = 30;
    static int healthPotDropChance = 50;
    static int ShieldDropChance = 0;
    static int enemyCounter = 0;
    static int defense = 0;
    static int enemyHealth = 0;
    
    static int damageDealt = 0;
    static int damageTaken = 0;

    //Items
    static boolean sword = false;
    static int swordDropChance = 0;
    
    static boolean running = true;
    
    static Entity enemy;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        welcome();

        GAME: while (running) {
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");

            
            int ra = rand.nextInt(enemies.length); //RANDOM ENEMY           SELECTION in two steps
            enemy = enemies[ra];            

//     enemy = enemies[rand.nextInt(enemies.length)]; //in one step

            System.out.println(ra);
            
            System.out.println("\t# " + enemy.name + " appeared! #\n");

            while (enemy.enemyHealth > 0) {

                monitoring(enemy, Entity.enemyHealth);

                String input = in.nextLine();
                if (input.equals("1")) {
                    damageDealt = rand.nextInt(attackDamage);
                    damageTaken = rand.nextInt(enemyAttackDam);
                    
                    enemy.enemyHealth -= damageDealt;
                    health -= damageTaken;

                    // Iteminfluence
                    health += defense;

                    System.out.println("\t> You strike the " + enemy.name + " for " + damageDealt + " damage.");
                    System.out.println("\t> You recive " + damageTaken + " in retaliation!");

                    if (health < 1) {
                        dead();
                        break;
                    }

                } else if (input.equals("2")) {
                    healingProcess(enemy);
                }

                else if (input.equals("3")) {
                    runOption(enemy);
                    continue GAME;
                }

                else {
                    System.out.println("\tInvalid command!");
                }
            }

            if (health < 1) {
                System.out.println("You limp out of the dungeon, weak from battle!");
                break;
            }

            defmsg(enemy);

            enemyC();

            healpot(enemy);

            defense(enemy);
            
            sword(enemy);

            options();
            
            String input = in.nextLine();
            
            while (!input.equals("1") && !input.equals("2")) {
                System.out.println("Invalid command!");
                input = in.nextLine();
            }

            if (input.equals(input.equals("1"))) {
                System.out.println("You continue on ypur adventure!");
            }

            else if (input.equals("2")) {
                System.out.println("You exit the dungeon, successful from your adventure!");
                break;
            }

        }
        thx();
    }



    private static void sword(Entity enemy) {
        
        if (rand.nextInt(100) < swordDropChance) {

            attackDamage += 5;

            System.out.println(" # The " + enemy.name + " dropped a piece of armor! # ");
            System.out.println(" # You attack now with +5! # ");

        }

        
    }



    private static void defmsg(Entity enemy) {
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(" # " + enemy.name + " was defeated! # ");
        System.out.println(" # You have " + health + "HP left. # ");
        
        enemy.enemyHealth = enemy.inHealth;
    }

    private static void options() {
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("What would you like to do now? ");
        System.out.println("1. Continue fighting");
        System.out.println("2. Exit dungeon");
    
    }

    private static void thx() {
        System.out.println("#######################");
        System.out.println("# THANKS FOR PLAYING! #");
        System.out.println("#######################");
    }

    private static void welcome() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Dungeon!");
        
    }

    private static void attack(int enemyHealth, int damageDealt, int damageTaken) {
        
        enemy.enemyHealth -= damageDealt;
        health -= damageTaken;

        // Iteminfluence
        health += defense;

    }

    private static void dead() {
        System.out.println("\t> You have taken too much damage, you are too weak to go on!");
    }

    private static void monitoring(Entity enemy, int enemyHealth) {
        System.out.println("\tYour HP: " + health);
        System.out.println("\t" + enemy.name + "'s HP: " + enemy.enemyHealth);
        System.out.println("\n\tWhat would you like to do?");
        System.out.println("\t1. Attack");
        System.out.println("\t2. Drink health potion");
        System.out.println("\t3. Run!");

    }

    private static void runOption(Entity enemy) {

        System.out.println("\tYou run away from the " + enemy.name + "!");

    }

    private static void healingProcess(Entity enemy) {

        if (numHealthPot > 0) {

            int prevHealth = health;

            health += healthPotHealAmount;

            if (health == 100) {
                System.out.println("You can not heal yourself!");
            } else if (health > 100) {
                health = 100;
                numHealthPot--;
                System.out.println("\t> You drink a health potion, healing yourself for " + healthPotHealAmount + " . "
                        + "\n\t> You now have " + health + " HP." + "\n\t> You have " + numHealthPot
                        + " health potions left.\n");

            } else {
                numHealthPot--;
                System.out.println("\t> You drink a health potion, healing yourself for " + healthPotHealAmount + " . "
                        + "\n\t> You now have " + health + " HP." + "\n\t> You have " + numHealthPot
                        + " health potions left.\n");

            }

        }

        else {
            System.out.println("\t> You have no health potions left! Defeat enemies for a chance to get one!");
        }

    }

    private static void enemyC() {

        enemyCounter++;

        if (enemyCounter == 1) {
            System.out.println(" # You killed one enemy! # ");
        } else {
            System.out.println(" # You killed " + enemyCounter + " enemies! # ");
        }

    }

    private static void healpot(Entity enemy) {
        if (rand.nextInt(100) < healthPotDropChance) {
            numHealthPot++;
            System.out.println(" # The " + enemy.name + " dropped a health potion! # ");
            System.out.println(" # You now have " + numHealthPot + " heaalth potion(s). # ");
        }

    }

    public static void defense(Entity enemy) {

        if (rand.nextInt(100) < ShieldDropChance) {

            defense += 5;

            System.out.println(" # The " + enemy.name + " dropped a piece of armor! # ");
            System.out.println(" # You now have " + defense + " defensepoints! # ");

        }

    }
}
```

I Tried to split the part up and print out the number it choose. And the random selection works but its always the same enemy which gets chosen.

```
public class Entity {

    static String name;
    static int enemyHealth = 100;
    static int ShieldDropChance = 0;
    static int swordDropChance = 0;
    static int inHealth = 0;
    
    public static int getSwordDropChance() {
        return swordDropChance;
    }
    public static void setSwordDropChance(int swordDropChance) {
        Entity.swordDropChance = swordDropChance;
    }
    public static int getShieldDropChance() {
        return ShieldDropChance;
    }
    public static void setShieldDropChance(int shieldDropChance) {
        ShieldDropChance = shieldDropChance;
    }
    public static String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public static void setName(String name) {
        Entity.name = name;
    }
    public static int getEnemyHealth() {
        return enemyHealth;
    }
    public static void setEnemyHealth(int enemyHealth) {
        Entity.enemyHealth = enemyHealth;
    }
    
    public Entity (String name, int enemyHealth, int ShieldDropChance, int swordDropChance, int inHealth) {
        
        this.name = name;
        this.enemyHealth = enemyHealth;
        this.ShieldDropChance = ShieldDropChance;
        this.swordDropChance = swordDropChance;
        this.inHealth = inHealth;
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: you should not split code with useless comments

Comment: add your entity class its probably the reason for the bug

Comment: @anon thx, I added the Entity class down below in the post.

Comment: yeah you need to remove the static part.  Static variables are class variables what you want is instance variables so you will need to remove it since every  time you change a static  variables it will change globaly for that class and thats the reason you are only getting assassin since it the last update you give the the class entity

Comment: What you are doing seems right to me. And welcome to Stack Overflow, but it’s much too much code, and I am by far reading through all of it. If you want serious answers, reduce to a [mre], please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? At least I find it very similar. [My Java object array only returns the last element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49016473/my-java-object-array-only-returns-the-last-element)

Answer (score 1):

What Anon said. Change your entity class to this, and you shouldn't even need to touch the rest of your code.

Remember that static means it's one value associated with the class itself and not any particular instance. But for some reason, Java lets you reference static values via an instance (like you did), which does nothing except trick you into thinking it's not static. I really don't know why that's a thing.

```java
public class Entity {

    String name;
    int enemyHealth = 100;
    int shieldDropChance = 0;
    int swordDropChance = 0;
    int inHealth = 0;
    
    public int getSwordDropChance() {
        return swordDropChance;
    }
    public void setSwordDropChance(int swordDropChance) {
        this.swordDropChance = swordDropChance;
    }
    public int getShieldDropChance() {
        return shieldDropChance;
    }
    public void setShieldDropChance(int shieldDropChance) {
        this.shieldDropChance = shieldDropChance;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getEnemyHealth() {
        return enemyHealth;
    }
    public void setEnemyHealth(int enemyHealth) {
        this.enemyHealth = enemyHealth;
    }
    
    public Entity (String name, int enemyHealth, int ShieldDropChance, int swordDropChance, int inHealth) {
        
        this.name = name;
        this.enemyHealth = enemyHealth;
        this.ShieldDropChance = ShieldDropChance;
        this.swordDropChance = swordDropChance;
        this.inHealth = inHealth;
        
        
    }
}
```